# How to make white model whiter in Three.js / Blender?

Tags: three.js, model, 3d, blender, modeling

How can I further whiten a model that is already white?
I want a model to look like that:[I want that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZtKJ.png)
In blender it looks like that: [Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yx65.png)
On site it looks like that: [Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDOxA.png)
Blender material settings: [Material settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zGFi.png)

That's my code:

```js
<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
  const parentElement = document.getElementById('thats-me-block')

  //Scene
  const scene = new THREE.Scene()

  let globalGltf
  const loader = new GLTFLoader()
  const modelUrl = new URL('./assets/untitled.glb', import.meta.url).href
  loader.load(
    modelUrl,
    function (gltf) {
      globalGltf = gltf.scene
      globalGltf.scale.set(6, 15, 6)
      globalGltf.rotation.set(0, -0.2, 0)
      scene.add(globalGltf)
    },
    undefined,
    function (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  )

  //Camera
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100)
  camera.position.set(0, 2.80, 5.5)
  scene.add(camera)

  const directionalLight = new THREE.SpotLight('#FFFFFF', 7500)
  directionalLight.position.set(7.5, 5.5, 2.5)
  scene.add(directionalLight)
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas.value,
    alpha: true,
    antialias: true
  })
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
  renderer.setSize(350, 250)
  parentElement.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

  function animate() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    if (globalGltf) {
      globalGltf.rotation.y -= 0.005
    }
  }

  renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate)

  function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    onWindowResize();
  })
})
</script>
```

Not quite the effect I wanted to achieve. Any ideas?
I am using Vue 3.0 and Three.js

Comment: Appearance is a combination of material settings (which you haven't shared – screencap the material's _settings_ in Blender?) and lighting. A spotlight won't be give soft diffuse lighting like you're describing, adding an ambient light would fill in areas the spotlight doesn't illuminate. Or THREE.RoomEnvironment is a good standalone option: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/b447ff2911cbefcd650df5a18a905e7df882fc78/examples/webgl_loader_gltf_compressed.html#L61-L67

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I've added a screenshot of the material settings. I'm not sure if that's what you meant, if you need anything else, let me know.

Comment: By default, a scene is pitch black. Adding a single spotlight is like pointing a flashlight into the room--you're going to get hard light an deep shadows. You'll need more lights, obviously, but what and how you configure them is up to you. Look into how photographers set up lights for portraits, then dig into [the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/) under "Lights" and see if you can use these to replicate different setups.

Comment: Also, what might get you by for now is adding a simple [AmbientLight](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/AmbientLight) which will add non-directional "fill light" to the entire scene.